# Python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully. Installing DRecPy

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, python-wheel

I try to install DRecPy library which installation is described [here](https://pypi.org/project/DRecPy/0.2.2/#installation).

Unfortunately, it does not work. I've tried installing it with **pip**, and direct installation using **setup.py**.
Both ways have errors.

The first one is as following:

```
Building wheels for collected packages: pandas
  Building wheel for pandas (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [1062 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
```

The second one is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "projectpath\DRecPy\setup.py", line 15, in <module>
    long_description = fh.read()
  File "path\Python310\lib\encodings\cp1250.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x88 in position 5916: character maps to <undefined>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there is a character in the readme that cannot be read with the set encoding. Since you already have the sourcecode, replace the line mentioned here:

```
File "projectpath\DRecPy\setup.py", line 15, in <module>
    long_description = fh.read()
```

with

```
long_description = ""
```

in the `setup.py` file. Then do

```
python setup.py install
```

Note though that this indicates that this package was not tested with python 3.10, so you might run into other issues here.

Also consider reporting this bug to the author of the package, by [posting it on github](https://github.com/fabioiuri/DRecPy/issues)

Comment: This solution does work, thanks! However, it generates the same error unfortunately but it works.

Answer (score 0):

I had installed version 3.12.0 and decided to uninstall and downgrade to 3.11.4. Via "pip install", I installed Jpype1 and tabula-py, which loads other packages in an orderly manner and solved the problem.

Comment: Welcome to SO. The problem was resolved a long time ago and with a clear consensus. In that case, please further explain how your answer complements the accepted one. In its currrent state, it should be a comment. You may convert it into a comment when you get commenting rights.